# Parsing jsonData from postman response

Tags: json, postman

I have such response body:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Any errors for orderId=12"
}
```

I need to store the orderId value from `message` to the `orderId` variable. But so far I can only store the `message` value completely:

```
pm.test("app should return error", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(400);
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.property("message");
    pm.collectionVariables.set("orderId", jsonData["message"]);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only single `=` in the message text, you can split the string and save it to the variable like:

```
var orderId = jsonData.message.split('=')[1];
pm.collectionVariables.set("orderId", jorderId);
```